# Total length of cable to connect 1-wire DS18B20 sensors without problem

Tags: temperature, pullup, cat5

Based on [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242816/how-many-ds18b20-temperature-sensors-can-i-connect-to-one-bus-arduino/529570#529570) topic and the connection that is proposed I would like to make two questions (if somebody has face the same problem/task). So can I connect the data cable to a raspberry GPIO and then the voltage and GND to an external power supply or I would have problem with the pull up resistor? Also, is it ok the last sensor to be 30 m far from the raspberry? or I would have reflections problems? I am thinking of using cat5 cable. Is it a good choice?

Comment: Ah, 30m is a bit long.  You might like to consider DS2482:  (1) DS2482 I2C to 1-Wire Bridge Connecting 10+ DS18B20 Temperature Sensors Using 30 Metres Long CAT5e Cables, Viewed 699 times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/111412/rpi3b-python-ds2482-i2c-to-1-wire-bridge-connecting-10-ds18b20-temperature-sen/111421#111421

(2) DS18B20 Temperature Sensor - Rpi 3/4 Driver, Wiring, Detection, and Python Programming - Viewed 1k times
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/100203/ds18b20-temperature-sensor-rpi-3-4-driver-wiring-detection-and-python-progr. Cheers.

Comment: It depends, cable rise time, 1-Wire topology and length, check https://www.loxone.com/enen/kb/wiring-1-wire-devices/

Comment: What relay? The question is only about One Wire and DS18B20!?!?!

Comment: You are right. I deleted the comment